# Why we don't use twisted cable in dc power?

Tags: power, dc, power-electronics, twisted-pair

I general applications, we don't see DC-Power lines as twisted pairs. Even in standard cables, only the data line pair is generally twisted. Do we assume that DC-power lines are not worth twisting? Or there is an undesirable effect on twisted DC-power cables?

Comment: "Or there is an undesirable effect on twisted DC-power cables?"
Unnecessary cost?

Comment: Hi! This is engineering. We never do something without a reason. Have you tried to figure out why data cables are twisted, and then asked yourself whether the same reason applies to power supply cables?

Comment: Mechanical reasons are probably worthy of mention.  A twisted set of wires stay together.

Comment: I think this is a great question and on topic. Can anyone help me understand why this had been downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data line is twisted because there are complex, noise susceptible signal inside.

Power lines are usually not twisted because there's no need for that and it's an added manufacturing expense. Also, twisted cable is bigger.

Twisting is done to reduce magnetic field influence on the cable (and, somewhat less, reduce effective radiated magnetic field); usually power lines have very low source impedance and don't actually really care about induced noise (in the general case). This is true for AC lines too. So it's only a trouble to twist them.

AFAIK there is no downside on running power down twisted cable aside of the added cost.

If you have significant current noise, twisting the power lines could help with magnetic emissions (it's often done with PWM driven DC motors).

Answer (score 2):

Twisted pairs are useful in mitigating radiated emissions and immunity from radiated emissions.  Electromagnetic interference is generated by AC signals, and tends to increase with frequency.  Therefore DC power doesn't generate interference except when switched on and off, and generally the low impedance means that immunity is good.  High-frequency cables such as CAT6 UTP are twisted, so they can be placed alongside DC cables and don't tend to emit or absorb interference.